# How to change the correct answer of a question and replicate exams from scratch when exshuffle is on (package 'exams')?

Tags: r-exams

I have the following question, where the argument of \exsolution is {0010} but it should be {1000}

```
\begin{question}
What is the capital of Italy

\begin{answerlist}
  \item Rome
  \item Paris
  \item Vienna
  \item Madrid
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0010}
\exshuffle{4}
```

I have corrected the error and re-run the processes of creating and grading exams from scratch using the same seed. Unfortunately, the sequence of answers in this question changes (note \exshuffle{4}), so the grades assigned to this particular question are wrong. All other questions are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way that `exshuffle` is implemented it is not easy to just change the `{answerlist}` and/or `exsolution` and get the right resulting exam.

Instead I would recommend to go through the meta-information and fix it there. I presume that you are generating the exams with `exams2nops()` and have stored the RDS with the metainformation, right? I will produce such a file via:

```
set.seed(1)
exams2nops(c("capitals.Rnw", "italy.Rnw", "switzerland.Rnw"), n = 5, dir = ".")
```

Thus, there are five exams with 3 exercises each with your problematic exercise `italy.Rnw` in second place. The metainformation is stored in `metainfo.rds` which we can read again via

```
x <- readRDS("metainfo.rds")
```

Now `x` is a list of 5 elements (exams), each of which has 3 elements (exercises), which have elements `question`, `questionlist`, `solution`, `solutionlist`, `metainfo`, and `supplements`. Here, we need to inspect the `questionlist` in order to fix the `metainfo$solution`. Currently, Vienna is marked as being correct:

```
x[[1]][[2]]$questionlist
## [1] "Madrid" "Vienna" "Rome"   "Paris" 
x[[1]][[2]]$metainfo$solution
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

However, it should be Rome:

```
x[[1]][[2]]$questionlist == "Rome"
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So we can loop through this and save the result. Just to be safe, we also store the original RDS file:

```
x <- readRDS("metainfo.rds")
file.copy("metainfo.rds", "metainfo-orig.rds")
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
  x[[i]][[2]]$metainfo$solution <- x[[i]][[2]]$questionlist == "Rome"
}
saveRDS(x, "metainfo.rds")
```

Final remark: There is also an element `metainfo$string` that is used when extracting `exams_metainfo()`. If we wanted to use that, we would need to fix the `$string` as well. But for `nops_eval()` it is sufficient to fix the `$solution`.

Comment: Nice! However, to make it more interesting, the question was randomly chosen from a pool of two questions, ie  c("italy.Rnw","germany.Rnw"). I wonder how the content of the loop changes.

Comment: Inside the `for()` loop you need to add `if(x[[i]][[2]]$metainfo$file == "italy")` so that the replacement of `$metainfo$solution` is only carried out when `metainfo$file` is the problematic file.

Comment: You're very welcome! Things like this actually were part of the reason why I put so much work into R/exams. Sometimes when using the tools provided by the university I would hit a wall at a certain point or would have to do a lot of manual checking. In R/exams I would at least write some R code to work around many problems...

Comment: speaking of which, I got two exams with different registration numbers but corrected according to the SAME Exam ID. It's kind of frustrating. I don't want to regret having decided using r/exams... Have you experienced something like this before?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here. In any case, it seems to be unrelated to the previous question. So please provide a reproducible example and post a new question - either here on SO or in our discussion forum on R-Forge. (The latter is easier for discussions that require iterative comments rather than a clear single answer.)

Comment: It seems the software wrongly read two exams IDs. Will do as you suggest

Comment: In many cases those problems come from suboptimal scanned images. Either students drew something where they shouldn't - or the scanner settings should be improved, e.g., a bit lighter or darker. In any case the software should warn you and ask for improvement (when run interactively).