# Change correct answer of exercise created with r-exams after openolat test was taken

Tags: r, r-exams, openolat

If an exam is created with r-exams, exported to openolat with `exams2openolat(exm, n = 50,...)` and already been taken by multiple students, OLAT grades the students automatically. After the test one finds that in one or more exercises there was a mistake e.g.one has written`\exsolution{000111}` instead of `\exsolution{000101}`. How could this be fixed, and the students points automatically adapted without going through all (maybe 200) students manually?

Maybe by importing the marked solutions back into R? Or can this somehow be done in OLAT directly?

I found a solution ([How to change the correct answer of a question and replicate exams from scratch when exshuffle is on (package 'exams')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897770/how-to-change-the-correct-answer-of-a-question-and-replicate-exams-from-scratch)) for scanned tests, but how can one do something similar in OLAT?

Comment: Did the answer below help or not? If you are still struggling with this also feel free to reach out directly and then we can see whether we can sort it out.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I only today was able to work at this some more. I really appreciate your effort! I could not get it working yet. (see comment under your answer)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no functionality for this in OpenOlat (other than doing it manually for each individual result). But there is the option to export a zipped version of the test which includes a self-contained version of the individual HTML pages and a summary table in .xlsx format. The latter can be read into R and processed further.

The export can be found in *Administration > Archive tool > Test*
(in German the *Archive tool* is called *Datenarchivierung*). When you unzip the resulting .zip file it contains a .xlsx file that is formatted somewhat inconveniently, especially if there are many random replications per exercise in the test. We have written some convenience functions for dealing with this that I have just put up in package `exams2openolat` on R-Forge. It can be installed with:

```
install.packages("exams2openolat", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

If you have the exported file, say `olattest.xlsx`, in the current working directory, then you can read it into a data frame with:

```
res <- exams2openolat:::read_olat_results("olattest.xlsx")
```

If you additionally have an .rds file `olattest.rds` with the output from `exams2openolat()` you can even get some more convenient results via:

```
res <- exams2openolat::olat_eval("olattest")
```

You probably haven't stored such an .rds when you generated the OpenOlat test but maybe you have kept the R code including random seed. If so, you can re-run the code after `library("exams2openolat")` which then not only creates the .zip file but also the .rds file along with it.

Comment: I have not actually an exam yet where this is a problem, but since I know that I regularly screw up I want to be sure to be able to fix these problems before using the r-exams system in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Using the fist method, I can import the points achieved into R, but the data frame I get has as many rows per person as there are versions of the test and also I can not see the points of the individual exercises, only the sums. Concerning the second method I get an error and a warning `Error in [.data.frame(res, , paste("points", 1L:k, sep = ".")) :    undefined columns selected In addition: Warning message: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :   row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded `

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and sorry that the solution so far didn't work. I just noticed that the current version of the functions in the `exams2openolat` package that I posted assumes German variable names inside the .xlsx file. So you would need to switch your language to German, export the data, and switch the language back. We have started internationalizing the code for this but I currently don't have a version that fully works. Sorry! (If the German setting also doesn't work, then you can maybe send me your an example file off-list, then I can have a look whether we can easily adjust.)